# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel not honoring KVO if text is empty? Apple bug?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, key-value-observing, iboutlet

I am experiencing strange behavior with a table view cell configured with right detail.  The cell is a static cell that is part of a table view controller created in storyboard.  In my view controller, I created an `IBOutlet UITextField *detail` that is connected to the cell detail.  So far so good.  The view is configured so that when the cell's accessory is hit, another controller is pushed onto the stack so that the user can enter text to display.  Upon return, detail.text is set to the user's string.  I'm relying on KVO between the IBOutlet and the detail in the storyboard for auto-updates.

The problem is that if `detail.text` is set to @"" (empty string, not nil) upon entry to the view, the cell's detail will *NOT* update regardless of how many times the user changes the text.  I can see via the debugger that detail reflects the user's changes, but the cell does not. The strange thing is that if I leave the view and re-enter so that detail.text is initialized to some non-empty string, all is fine.  This problem does not occur if the initial value of detail.text is something other than an empty string.  The user can change the text all he wants and upon return the cell reflects the changes.

Apple bug, or am I missing something?

Regards,

--John

Comment: Why don't you help me out with that.....

Comment: I found the same issue. KVO is not firing up for empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a reload when the cell has to be redrawn.

```
[tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I know that's a work around, as that's what I am currently doing to get around the problem.  But the underlying problem still exists - it does not work when the initial text is an empty string.  Why is that?

Comment: It should not be working without refreshing the cell. It is erratic that it is updating, not that it is not updating - but so what?. So updating with `reloadData` is the correct way to go, not a "work around".

Answer (score 0):

I've found that setting the text to @" " (with a space) instead of @"" solves the problem. The next time you will update the label with a non empty string it will be updated as expected.